# How do I get the user's name, email, and profile picture when the user logs in with their Facebook account?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have been able to create a successful login with the user's Facebook account on my android app. Now, I want to be able to get the user's name, email, and profile picture.

Similar to what I did when the user logs in with their Google account:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
String name = account.getDisplayName();
String email = account.getEmail();
String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
Name.setText(name);
Username.setText(email);
Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(Prof_Pic);
```

The above code shows what I did when the user logged in with their Google account. I want to pretty much do the same thing when the user logs in with their Facebook account. What do I do?

Comment: You need to look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) and implement.

Comment: Unrelated: variable should start lower case. So Name, Username are rather wrong. And no"_" chars either. Thus consider learning about Java naming conventions to avoid confusing your readers.

Comment: @RumitPatel I've looked at that link. It doesn't say anything about getting the user's name, email, and profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you get the user facebook accessToken :

```
public static void getFacebookUserInfo(AccessToken accessToken,
                                       GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback callback) {
    if (accessToken == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("AccessToken should not be null !");
    }

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "name, email");
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, loginCallback);
    request.setParameters(params);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

and the callback :

```
private class FacebookUserInfoCallback implements GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
        if (response.getError() == null) {
            String name = object.optString("name");
            String email = object.optString("email");
        }
    }
}
```

and get the profile picture(should be call after facebook user logged in) :

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
if(profile != null) {
    Uri profilePictureUri = profile.getProfilePictureUri(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Should I put this all in the `onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)`?

Comment: @BertHanz nope,put it where you like,but u can put it on where u wanna get those info